# How to show speed and position in Apex Legends

Tags: apex-legends

In [this video](https://reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/ik2hus/i_was_challenged_to_slide_down_this_hill_even/), MokeySniper has an FPS counter on the upper-right hand of the screen that shows his login name, FPS, and strangely, his position, angle, and speed.

I would like to also have this position information available. I know that `-cl_showfps 1` will  show the FPS, but I’m not sure how to show position as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+cl_showpos 1`
This will show position and velocity on the top left corner of the screen.